# Construyo una apk con React-Native, pero no funciona en mi tablet

Tags: android, react-native, apk

soy nuevo en React Native. Construyo una apk que funciona en mi teléfono, pero no funciona en mi tablet y no sé por qué no funciona.

Mi tablet dice "Error de análisis: se produjo un problema al analizar el paquete"

Es un Galaxy Tab E - Android: 4.4.4

Necesito ayuda con esto, por favor.

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Solo Carnes Vinos",
    "slug": "solocarnesvinos",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "android":{
      "package":"com.agenciafina.solocarnesvinos",
      "versionCode":2,
      "permissions":[]
    },
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```